# When migrating from restful_authentication to Devise do I need to change the sessions and user controller?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, restful-authentication, controllers

When I migrate from restful_authentication to devise it will show the main page, but then it complains that it can't find restful_authentication commands.  What do I need to do to fix this? Do I need to replace the user and sessions controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise will generate new user controllers, the session controllers are okay.  You must make sure to remove all of restful_authentications links in Application_controller and so on and so forth, then you must change resources :users to devise_for :users in routes.rb then it should work with a bit of tweaking like setting the root to another controller and adding before_filter :authenticate_user! to that model so that it will go to the login screen (assuming you want this functionality).

Comment: What are the restful authentication links? Do you have a list of them? how should one replace it with devise links?

Answer (score 1):

For migrating from restful_authentication to devise, devise wiki page will be helpful for you.

Visit https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Migrate-from-restful_authentication-to-Devise